# How can I change numberPicker speed in Android java/xml

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-number-picker

How can I change the speed of numberPicker?
My number picker:

```
  <NumberPicker android:id="@+id/numberpicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
                    />
```

Comment: Move your finger at a different speed? What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: @MikeM. I want to change the maximum speed, it would be possible to move more quickly

Answer (score 3):

The default value is 300 ms.
The speed (in milliseconds) at which the numbers will be incremented and decremented.

```
public static final long SPEED_UPDATE_PICKER = 500;
mPicker.setOnLongPressUpdateInterval(SPEED_UPDATE_PICKER );
```